# node.js - issue with Arabic character encoding

Tags: node.js, json, encoding, httpresponse, arabic

I'm using node.js and express to send a *json* file to client. The String in the database is something like "السلام", but the output of *json* in the browser looks like this **"Ù‡Ø§ÛŒ Ù¾Ø§ØªØ§ÛŒØ§"**.
Now the Jquery(or maybe something else) in the browser correctly decodes this into arabic, but in the android app, it's still an alien language.
How can I make this string converted into valid Arabic?
The code is pretty simple:

```
return res.json({result: resultFromDB});
```

even if I did something like this:

```
return res.json({result: "John Döm"});
```

it would give something like {"result":"John DÃ¶m"}

Comment: express by default uses utf-8 for json, and I have manully converted it to utf-8 too, but it doesn't work

Comment: use encoding when reading from DB and when sending to client, please insert the code in the question to check the problem deeply.

Comment: the problem isn't from the DB, because even when I insert the string manually it'd show me the wrong encoding.

Comment: try to read the json (using code not browser) using encoding utf-8 and check if the string is valid

Comment: in android java the encoding wouldn't get magically fixed, but in browser it does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79852/discussion-between-safwan-hijazi-and-user3425760).

Comment: It seems to me the Android app is incorrectly assuming that the string is Latin-1 encoded.

Comment: maybe but why can't I correctly get the response in utf-8?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
res.json('{"result":"السلام"}')
```

Comment: That's not valid JS. If you meant `res.json('{"result":"السلام"}')`, the response will be a single JSON _string_ and not an _object_.

Comment: @robertklep: won't an object get stringified (serialized) anyway?

Comment: As you said it will be json string, and from client side he will parse it as string

Comment: @bardzusny the code above creates a JSON representation of a string, not a JSON representation of an object. The JSON itself obviously will be a string.

Comment: @SafwanHijazi but the _String_ `{"result":"السلام"}` is fundamentally different from the _Object_ `{result:"السلام"}`. If the OP is happy with that, that's fine, but it's not what was asked. If a string is good enough, why not just use `res.send()` instead of `res.json()`?

Comment: Thanks for calcification, but after long discussion and many tries to encode json, and he said it failed, we tried to send json as string and it works fine, and he accepted that solution. Also he can use res.send.